# Medalha Necromante Parece Mal Escrita

Tags: debate, tradução, medalhas

Desculpa se isso for uma questão boba, mas me confundiu agora quando eu achei que fosse ganhá-la.

A medalha Necromante diz o seguinte:

> Respondeu uma pergunta com mais de 60 dias e 5 ou mais pontos

Com esta descrição, me parece lógico que para ganhá-la você deve dar uma resposta para uma pergunta que tenha mais de 60 dias e a própria pergunta deve ter mais de 5 pontos.

Porém não parece ser esse o caso depois que eu vi as situações onde se ganharam essa medalha. Pelo que eu entendi, a descrição da medalha deveria ser:

> Deu uma resposta com 5 ou mais pontos para uma pergunta com mais de 60 dias

Comment: Acredito que o texto é uma tradução literal [da versão da matriz](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer), que é igualmente ambígua.

Comment: @Renan Parece igualmente confusa mesmo.

Comment: Acho que poderia ser assim: `Respondeu uma pergunta com mais de 60 dias, onde a resposta alcance 5 ou mais pontos`.

Comment: A versão em inglês é menos ambígua - em português a gente conecta as duas informações porque elas estão juntas: "60 dias e 5 pontos" - em inglês, está escrito: "responda uma pergunta *mais de 60 dias depois*" - a segunda parte da frase se refere ao ato de responder, o que desconecta "escore de 5 pontos" da palavra "pergunta". Essa frase poderia ser reescrita assim: "responda com escore de 5 ou mais pontos uma pergunta mais de 60 dias depois", com exatamente o mesmo significado (isso tudo na minha opinião, obviamente).

Answer (score 7):

Ótima [sugestão do @ramaral](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5909/medalha-necromante-parece-mal-escrita/5936?noredirect=1#comment22658_5936)

> Obteve 5 ou mais pontos numa resposta dada pelo menos 60 dias após a pergunta

Que tal?

No ar no próximo build.

Comment: Deveria ser "*Conseguiu 5 ou mais pontos numa resposta dada pelo **menos** 60 dias depois da pergunta*"

Comment: @ramaral faz a barba! :D

Comment: Proponho "Obteve 5 ou mais pontos numa resposta dada pelo menos 60 dias após a pergunta"

Comment: @ramaral gostei muito mais, também 